# How do I restore `/dev/log` in systemd+rsyslog host?

Tags: systemd-journald, rsyslogd

On RHEL7, `systemd-journald` takes over many of the responsibilites of what was once done by `rsyslogd`. Whether by bug or conflict between these two daemons, sometimes `/dev/log` will go missing. As a result, programs relying on the `syslog(3)` call will not function properly, including, for instance, `logger`. How can I restore the `/dev/log` socket?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Asking and answering my own question because Google was not very helpful on this one.

Normally, with `rsyslogd`, the `imuxsock` module will create the `/dev/log` socket on its own, unlinking the previous entry before creating it. When `rsyslogd` is stopped (possibly because restart which fails because of faulty configuration), **rsyslogd removes** `/dev/log`.

However, the rsyslog supplied with `RHEL7` is expected to be used in conjunction with `systemd`, and the `imuxsock` module will actually open and remove `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` socket. Meanwhile, the `/dev/log` device is created by the system service-file `systemd-journald.socket` which triggers `journald`.

Apparently, whether or not `$imjournal` module is used, the following works.

In sum, if `/dev/log` disappears:

1. restart systemd-journald.socket:

   ```
   systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
   ```
2. then restart rsyslogd

   ```
   systemctl start rsyslogd
   ```

UPDATE: I believe `systemctl restart rsyslogd` might re-delete the socket if `rsyslogd` is already running.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I just lost several hours tracking down why logging wasn't working for a service.  I finally tracked it down to the missing /dev/log, which lead me to your solution.

Answer (score 5):

The `systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket && systemctl restart rsyslog` solution did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Instead, I had to recreate `/dev/log` as a symlink to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`:

```
ln -s /run/systemd/journal/dev-log /dev/log
```

Comment: Yes, manually linking should work as well. But it's a bit unwieldy to remember. Question: On Ubuntu does `systemd-journald.socket` exist as a service? Q2: maybe the `restart rsyslogd` was the problem? Maybe it should simply be `start rsyslogd`?

Comment: Q1: yes, it exists. Q2: there's no `restart` command anymore, there's `service` and `/etc/init.d/rsyslog`.

Comment: By `restart rsyslogd` I thought it was clear I meant `systemctl restart rsyslogd`. Does Ubuntu still use init scripts for rsyslog?

Comment: @Otheus `/etc/init.d/rsyslog stop` followed by `/etc/init.d/rsyslog start` did not help. Neither did `systemctl stop syslog.socket rsyslog.service && systemctl start syslog.socket rsyslog.service` On my system there's both `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` and `/etc/init.d/rsyslog`. Anyway, I'd rather not spend more time on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how the nuts and bolts of systemd and rsyslog work, but I tinkered on it for a while, and found why `/dev/log` disappears and how to restore it.

As mentioned in previous answers, Rsyslog will generate `/dev/log` socket by itself when the service starts if the imuxsock module is set in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, and remove the socket once the service stops. According to the [imuxsock documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html#imuxsock-systemd-details-label), rsyslog will only remove the socket if it was NOT passed in via systemd. In this case, `/dev/log` socket was passed in with rsyslog and not systemd, thus, it removes the socket if the service stops.

By default (I am using Fedora 36), rsyslog uses imuxsock module but with the "SysSock.Use=off" parameter. With this, rsyslog will not use the system log socket (`/dev/log`) as its socket, and thus, not generate `/dev/log`. Using this configuration (`module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.use="off")`) in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` will result in rsyslog not logging anything.

However, there is also another module loaded by default, which is the imjournal module. This gains rsyslog access to the systemd journal. From what I understood, rsyslog will not be the one generating `/dev/log` socket, rather systemd-journal-dev-log.socket will. This `/dev/log` socket will be symlinked to `/run/systemd/journal/dev-log`. Even if `module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.use="off")` is used, rsyslog will still log activities since it pulls data from systemd journal. Now that `/dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log` is created, rsyslog will not remove this since the socket was passed in via systemd.

From what I have tried, `/dev/log` could disappear because "SysSock.use=off" parameter is later added or uncommented in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (even if imjournal module was loaded). This tells rsyslog to not generate `/dev/log`.

You could say that adding the imjournal module again and restarting the service would solve this problem; however, the confusing part is that this does not work and no `/dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log` can be found. This is because the systemd-journald-dev-log.socket service was not aware that `/dev/log` socket is missing. Thus, restarting this service would trigger it that the socket is missing, then restarting the systemd-journald.socket afterwards will solve this problem. Although I am not sure that restarting the systemd-journald-dev-log.socket service is okay, this brings the `/dev/log` socket back.

In summary, do the following to get the `/dev/log` socket back:

1. Make sure you have these in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

   - `module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.use="off")`
   - `module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state")`
2. Restart rsyslog

   ```
   # systemctl restart rsyslog
   ```
3. Restart systemd-journald-dev-log.socket (you may see 'Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details.' warning, but I think it is okay since it stops and starts immediately)

   ```
   # systemctl restart systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
   ```
4. Restart systemd-journald.socket

   ```
   # systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
   ```

Note 1: From what I understand, this works only with RHEL system. Debian or Ubuntu-based systems may not have this problem, or different ways to solve it

Note 2: I am sorry for the long and confusing answer. 
This is my first time here and I am still a newbie :D

Comment: having a related problem on ubuntu 20.04.  not sure why but sometimes it works on boot and sometimes it doesn't.  /dev/log is there and points ok but doesn't work.  restarting systemd-journald-dev-log.socket fixes it without the other changes you mentioned.

Comment: I think ubuntu has a different file structure for logs. There is a `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` in ubuntu, but not in fedora (or RHEL-based systems, I think), which is why the answered method may not directly fit. There is also a process called "syslog.socket" in ubuntu, but not in fedora. I think if you have logs related problems in ubuntu, maybe try restarting this "syslog.socket" service as well.

Comment: yeah i tried that but it didn't work.  only `systemd-journald-dev-log.socket` worked and i only tried it because of your answer.  thanks.

Comment: For me this works on ArchLinux. Much thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

For me this ended up being a problem with how the imuxsock module used in rsyslog was working with systemd.

In the [imuxsock documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html#imuxsock-systemd-details-label) they walk through how the module is supposed to work for systemd. Step 1 was where I was seeing issues:

> Step 1: Select name of system socket
>
> 1. If the user has not explicitly chosen to set SysSock.Use="off" then the default listener socket (aka, “system log socket” or simply “system socket”) name is set to /dev/log. Otherwise, if the user has explicitly set SysSock.Use="off", then rsyslog will not listen on /dev/log OR any socket defined by the SysSock.Name parameter and the rest of this section does not apply.
> 2. If the user has specified sysSock.Name="/path/to/custom/socket" (and not explicitly set SysSock.Use="off"), then the default listener socket name is overwritten with /path/to/custom/socket.
> 3. Otherwise, if rsyslog is running under systemd AND /run/systemd/journal/syslog exists, (AND the user has not explicitly set SysSock.Use="off") then the default listener socket name is overwritten with /run/systemd/journal/syslog.

The system should have fallen through to Step 3 and changed the default path to be "/run/systemd/journal/syslog", but instead it stayed "/var/log". This meant that the imuxsock module would try (and succeed sometimes) to create a socket at /dev/log where there should instead be symbolic link created by the systemd-journald-dev-log.socket. In the case that it would fail to create the real socket, the symbolic link would still be removed.

That documentation was the outcome of [this issue](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/issues/397) reported on the rsyslog github. If you want to skip the discussion and jump straight to the changes see [PR#1](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/pull/427/files) and [PR#2](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc/pull/436/files) respectively.

My solution was to just configure the imuxsock module to use the systemd path in my /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
module(load="imuxsock"
    SysSock.Name="/run/systemd/journal/syslog")
```

This seems to have fixed my issue and sounds like a good solution here since it would explain why the symbolic link might disappear again after you would manually create it.

If you look on your system and "/run/systemd/journal/syslog" is not present look at the "syslog.socket" to see if it is starting successfully as that is what is responsible for creating the socket.

```
systemctl status syslog.socket
```

It could be that your version of rsyslog.service doesn't define syslog.service as an alias which is needed as the syslog.socket tries to active that service. It is also possible that multiple logging services try to alias syslog.service in which case last to be enabled wins.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough answer. It's mind-boggling how convoluted this all is. I blame systemd. :-D