# system log stop logging

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

[Was trying to enable log for chroot users](https://askubuntu.com/q/935017/104412)
May have done sth. wrong ,find `ls -l` in `/var/log` most log files size stay 0.
Try to fix it followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317066/224475)

```
# systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
# systemctl start rsyslogd
Failed to start rsyslogd.service: Unit rsyslogd.service not found.
```

[and this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125000/224475)

```
# logger -s "hellow"
logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory
# sudo rsyslogd -N6 | head -10
sudo: unable to resolve host iZ26v45oj3yjtmZ
rsyslogd: version 8.16.0, config validation run (level 6), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]

# ls /dev/log
ls: cannot access '/dev/log': No such file or directory
```

And checked syslogd is running

```
#lsof -f -p 5379
syslogd 5379 root   16w   REG              253,1        0    1844521 /var/log/news/news.err
syslogd 5379 root   17w   REG              253,1        0    1844536 /var/log/news/news.notice
syslogd 5379 root   18w   REG              253,1     3282    1580873 /var/log/debug.1 (deleted)
syslogd 5379 root   19w   REG              253,1   110492    1580898 /var/log/messages.1 (deleted)
syslogd 5379 root   20u  FIFO                0,6      0t0        423 /dev/xconsole
syslogd 5379 root   21u  unix 0xffff880138be9400      0t0     212524 /dev/log type=DGRAM
```

The /etc/rsyslog.conf file

```
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
#module(load="imudp")
#input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
#module(load="imtcp")
#input(type="imtcp" port="514")
# Enable non-kernel facility klog messages
$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

The /etc/syslog.conf file

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for inetutils-syslogd.
#
#                       For more information see syslog.conf(5) manpage.

#
# First some standard logfiles.  Log by facility.
#

auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
uucp.*                          /var/log/uucp.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

# Logging for INN news system
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some `catch-all' logfiles.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         *

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.crit;news.err;news.notice;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Problems here are:
  1.

> Failed to start rsyslogd.service

2.

> ls: cannot access '/dev/log': No such file or directory

3. `ls -l /var/log` most log file's size is 0

Comment: stop rsyslog service and run `sudo rsyslogd -dn`. See what does it say ? Also, have you made any file in `/etc/rsyslog.d` ?

Comment: the output of `sudo rsyslogd -dn` is too much ,I put it on the main post.`# ls /etc/rsyslog.d` shows `20-ufw.conf  50-default.conf`

Comment: no dont post the output, it will give every single line. Just see what they say here. If you find anything helpful, post that thing. Or I would suggest you to open an issue in rsyslog github repo, https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/new

Comment: Thank you @Luv33preet I remove the output,how ever the output is too long to read.Which part or keyword should be care?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot log inside a chroot because you need a /dev/log relative to the root of your chroot. (this is a known "feature").

Back in `rsyslog`, you add the a similar configuration to this one:

```
/etc/rsyslogd.conf
$AddUnixListenSocket /chroots/user1/dev/log
```

And restart `rsyslog` (outside the chroot)

See [How to log internal-sftp chroot jailed users](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/672633)

Comment: `ls /etc/rsyslogd.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/rsyslogd.conf': No such file or directory` So I changed `rsyslog.conf ` and restart rsyslog,but `logger -s "Hello w"` still complains `logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.How to recover it?Guess the /chroot/dev/log was wrong made but romove the /dev/log by mistake.